# CSS paper shadow effect is getting cut-off because of parent's background color

Tags: html, css

I have this simple paper shadow effect for a div, but it's getting ruined whenever I set the parent's background-color property.  Here's what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/9qahjjwx/

Below is the code.  How do I get around this provided that I'll be using a background-color on the parent?

**HTML**

```
<section class="block1">
  <div class="onpaper effect2">
    <h2>Has Background Color on the parent</h2>
    <p>This block has background color in its parent that's ruining the shadow effect (due to z-index?)</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="block2">
  <div class="onpaper effect2">
    <h2>No Background Color</h2>
    <p>This block has <b>no</b> background color in its parent by changing the class..</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.block1 {
    background-color: #f7f4e8;
    height: 200%;
}
.block2 {
    height: 200%;
}


.onpaper {
  margin:40px auto;
  width:75%;
  background-color: #d9d8c5;
  padding: 3% 6%;
}

.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add a z-index to the container and set it lower than the shadows: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/AgFJe

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another wrapper element in between, like so:

```
<section class="block">
   <div class="in-between">
      <div class="onpaper effect2">
         <h2>Has Background Color on the parent</h2>
         <p>This block has background color in its parent that's not ruining the shadow effect</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.in-between {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

That is ugly, but it works without setting a negative z-index on the parent (which might get you into trouble with the parent's parent).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a negative `z-index` and set the `position` to `relative` on `.block2`

```
.block2 {
    height: 200%;
    background-color: #f7f4e8;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/9qahjjwx/2/)**

Comment: The updated fiddle seem the same, the box-shadow isn't showing up

Comment: @alchuang No, not same. There are two divs on the fiddle, `box-shadow` is present in the second div.